# jQuery - Creating Pull Down Toolbar Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey so I have an html/php page that has a tool bar that spans the whole width of the top of the browser and about 45 pixels down from the top.  The tool bar is contained in a `<div>` and styled using CSS.  I want the bar to be able to be dragged down a set height and when the user releases the bar it snaps back to it's original position and performs a task (i.e. a reload or something cool with `$.ajax`).  I want the bar to be able to grow and shrink in height as the user drags it in the y plane.  I have completed a partial solution using the jquery ui widget draggable.  Here is my code:

```
//functions that handles topBarWrapper drags
$('.topBarWrapper').draggable({
    axis : 'y',
    appendTo : '.mainVideoPage',

    drag: function( event, ui ) {
        //Possible place to set height?
    },

    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        //resset offset and perfrom reload here
        $( this ).offset({ top: 0, left: 0 })
    }
});
```

The above code is almost complete.  I am able to pull done the `<div>` and upon release it snaps back to it's original offset and does something.  I can't seem to get the height working, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about actually changing the height, but... here's a solution that involves hiding some of the draggable content above the viewport and constraining the drag to an appropriately-sized and positioned container (check the fiddle, hard to tell what this is doing just from these snippets):

http://jsfiddle.net/U2CRH/

```
<div class="topbar-container">
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="topsection">
            <div>Pull down to refresh...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dragger">Pull down...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.topbar-container {
    height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-100px;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
.topbar {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
.topsection {
    height:100px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
.topsection div {
    padding-top:50px;
}
.dragger {
    height:50px;
    background-color:lightgreen;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

---

```
$('.topbar').draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    appendTo: '.mainVideoPage',
    containment: 'parent',

    drag: function (event, ui) {
        //...
    },

    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.offset().top >= -20) {
            //perform reload
        } else {            
            $this.animate({
                'top': '0'
            });
        }
    }
});
```